# How to access a window environmental variable from my angular app?

Tags: angular, variables, window, environment

I have been trying several codes to access an OS (Window 10 Home) environmental variable from my web application generated with Angular CLI version 6.1.5. without success. 
Same error message "property/variable X does not exist or can't be found".

I have tried:

`window.Key_ENV_Var;`
`rocess.env.Key_ENV_Var;`

I appreciate some help!

Comment: You can't-- Angular is a client side app, i.e. it runs in the browser. The browser does not have access to environment variables for security reasons. _(Plus the value would be different for every user, so I'm  not sure what you're trying to achieve...)_

Comment: You need a wrapper which as a set of APIs to communicate with the OS, Such as Electron.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can add some env variables for you angular app.

In angular app generated using Angular CLI you should have a folder called environments. In this folder you can add different configurations for different environment that you use. For example

- environment.ts (default)

  export const environment = {
      production: false,
      name: 'local',
      api: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1'
  };
- environment.prod.ts

  export const environment = {
      production: true,
      name: 'production',
      api: '/api/v1'
  };

Then in the file .angular-cli.json you can specify your environments like this

```
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

To use it in your app you need import environment

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

and you can use it

```
http.get(`${environment.api}/some-url`)
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations but I'm trying to handle the api_key putting it out of my code, for security purposes (because I will share my code in Github). If defining a const environment is the only way to deals with environmental variables in angular I should find another solution. How will you hide the value of a variable when working with an angular application (client side)??